# How to load products based on category selection that the user selected using mongoose and nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, node-modules

`Here is the scenario: the client choosed category type then in the products selection i want to load only the products that belongs to this category`

what i tried is to use `one function to get all categories which will return all categories`
and the other one `is to get the productCategory based on the category selection that the user select it`. but that gives me error in the ejs file that `productCategory` the variable that i passed in the second function is not defined.

`the callback function`

```
    exports.makeABill = (req, res, next) => {

    console.log('get Bill page');

    categoryDB.find({}, function(err, data) {

        res.render('bill/makeABill.ejs', { categories: data });

    });

    // categoryDB.findOne(req.body.categoryName, function(err, result) {

    //     res.render('bill/makeABill.ejs', { productCategory: result });
    // });



}
```

`the two input`

```
    <label for="categoryName"> Category : </label>

    <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="categoryName" autofocus>   
            <option value="">Select Category</option>

            <% categories.forEach(function (category) {%>
                <option> <%= category.categoryName %> </option>

                <%})%>

    </select>
    <br>
    <!--product-->
    <label for="productsCategory"> Product Name : </label>

    <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="productsCategory" name="productsCategory" autofocus>
        <option value="">Select Product</option>

        <% productCategory.forEach(function (category) {%>
            <option> <%= category.productsCategory %> </option>

            <%})%>
        
    </select>

    <br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try  this for filter `{columName : values}`

```
categoryDB.findOne({categoryName : req.body.categoryName}, function(err, result) {
     res.render('bill/makeABill.ejs', { productCategory: result });
 });
```

Comment: it gives me an error that `productCategory` which its the variable that i am passing to the ejs file. that his variable is not defined. do u have any other solution